# 301 Redirect Rule is not working when I use full URL

Tags: redirect, web-config, iis-7.5

I have a rule in my web.config on asp.net 4.5 and iis 7.5

```
<rule name="baad4041-5e25-499f-abb7-6bd4f76b2ed3" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="http://www.domain.com/ThisIsOld.html" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/NewUrl.aspx" />
  </rule>
```

It does not seem to work, when I hit the url, it sends me to my 404.  But this rule works:

```
<rule name="baad4041-5e25-499f-abb7-6bd4f76b2ed3" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="ThisIsOld.html" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/NewUrl.aspx" />
  </rule>
```

I need to have the full url as the match as this site has multiple domains, how can I make that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try;

```
<rule name="test" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
         <match url="http://www.domain.com/ThisIsOld.html" />
         <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.domain.com/NewUrl.html" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, took me a little while to try it, worked perfect

Comment: What is the difference between the rewrite and redirect? Does it make a difference for SEO if it is a rewrite as apposed to a redirect?

Comment: <rule name="URL1"  patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
      <match url="http://www.xyzq.com/Products/25/65/GPO-Stylo/"  />
      <action  type="Rewrite"  url="http://www.xyzq.com/record-players/gpo-stylo-ii/" />
    </rule>